# CouchDB Reducing Web Requests from UUID Requests

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to automatically assign a UUID to a CouchDB document? Right now, I have to do two web requests to create a new field in CouchDB - I'd like to reduce that to one if possible.

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/_uuids
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af \
 -d '{"_rev":"1-2902191555","title":"There is Nothing Left to Lose","artist":"Foo Fighters","year":"1997"}'
```

How can I combine those two requests into one PUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new document, if you do a POST rather than a PUT, CouchDB will fill in the _id for you. Make sure you set the Content-Type to application/json when doing the POST.

```
$curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/ \
>  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>  -d '{"title":"There is Nothing Left to Lose","artist":"Foo      Fighters","year":"1997"}'
{"ok":true,"id":"41af96d0685bf6535885685c9732055e","rev":"1-7a4ee0b846c0d1cb6308d0769ef041bf"}
```